# Where in the writings of the Vilna Gaon does he discuss how Rashi & Tosfot each explain a Talmudic "sugiya?"

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, rashi, vilna-gaon, tosfot

Two days ago, I asked this question in the name of the Vilna Gaon. I was informed that the answer may be [also] found in the writings of Rav Chaim Volozhin.

So, I re-phrased the question.

My understanding is that Rav Chaim Volozhin writes that Rashi adheres to the "simple" understanding of the Talmudic text, & Tosafot moves away from the simple understanding in order to reconcile [at least] two contradictory Talmudic texts. Where does Rav Chaim Volozhin write this explanation?

בברכה יוסף מקלר

ORIGNAL POSTING
My understanding is that the Vilna Gaon writes that Rashi adheres to the "simple" understanding of the Talmudic text, & Tosafot moves away from the simple understanding in order to reconcile [at least] two contradictory Talmudic texts. Where does he do so?

Comment: Does anyone not say that?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Baalei Tosfot might have argued that their reading is simple :)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yosef. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Where did you see that the Vilna Gaon discusses this?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is in the sefer Kerem Yehoshua by R. Yehoshua Cohen.